# Making a separate subdomain for mobile site - why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile-website

From my observations, many of well known websites (such as Facebook) having a separate subdomain for mobile site version (e.g. "m.facebook.com").

Theoretically, the decision which view to render can be done on server side based on device capabilities - all this on the same domain, transparent to end users.

So, my question is - why all this extra effort related to subdomain routing is required? Why it is so important (is it?) to present mobile version on separate subdomain? Is there some additional considerations, such as SEO?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Facebook and other social networks, it is for UI-design, for SEO optimization, and functionality, also details (such as fonts, image sizes, so on).

Comment: Everything related to UI may be achieved by conditional server side rendering, on the same domain. You don't need for that a separate subdomain. Please elaborate how exactly SEO optimization is related to separate subdomain. Thanks

Comment: @illidan try to zoom in Full version of facebook and see, how it works... As you can notice, full version and mobile version - it is almost two different systems